# Renci SSH.Net Connect Cancel

Tags: ssh, ssh.net

I'm working with the Renci SSH.Net library and creating SSH and SFTP connections to devices.  However, I don't see any way to cancel a connection that is in progress.  For example, the user has mistyped the address they want to connect to and doesn't want to wait for the connection to time out.

Is there a way to cancel this connection or am I forced to wait for the timeout?